# Recursive lambda expression to traverse a tree in C#

Tags: c#, recursion, lambda

Can someone show me how to implement a recursive lambda expression to traverse a tree structure in C#.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Ok, I found some free time finally.
Here we go:

```
class TreeNode
{
    public string Value { get; set;}
    public List<TreeNode> Nodes { get; set;}


    public TreeNode()
    {
        Nodes = new List<TreeNode>();
    }
}

Action<TreeNode> traverse = null;

traverse = (n) => { Console.WriteLine(n.Value); n.Nodes.ForEach(traverse);};

var root = new TreeNode { Value = "Root" };
root.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode { Value = "ChildA"} );
root.Nodes[0].Nodes.Add(new TreeNode { Value = "ChildA1" });
root.Nodes[0].Nodes.Add(new TreeNode { Value = "ChildA2" });
root.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode { Value = "ChildB"} );
root.Nodes[1].Nodes.Add(new TreeNode { Value = "ChildB1" });
root.Nodes[1].Nodes.Add(new TreeNode { Value = "ChildB2" });

traverse(root);
```

Comment: IIRC the ForEach extension method doesn't exist in the Framework, so you have to write it yourself (which is an easy task).

Comment: `ForEach` is an existing instance method of `List<T>`.

Answer (score 33):

A proper solution, and indeed the idiomatic solution in many functional programming languages, would be the use of a [fixed-point combinator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_combinator). In a nutshell: a fixed-point combinator answers the question “how do I define an anonymous function to be recursive?”. But the solution is so nontrivial that whole articles are written to explain them.

A simple, pragmatic alternative is to “go back in time” to the antics of C: declaration before definition. Try the following (the “factorial” function):

```
Func<int, int> fact = null;
fact = x => (x == 0) ? 1 : x * fact(x - 1);
```

Works like a charm.

Or, for a pre-order tree traversal on an object of class `TreeNode` which implements `IEnumerable<TreeNode>` appropriately to go over its children:

```
Action<TreeNode, Action<TreeNode>> preorderTraverse = null;
preorderTraverse = (node, action) => {
    action(node);
    foreach (var child in node) preorderTraverse(child, action);
};
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, how this factorial function can help to answer on given question?

Comment: because it's recursive

Comment: It's easier for other users to understand the solution if it's in a commonly considered recursive function than it would be having to understand OP's specific problem.

Answer (score 18):

> A simple alternative is to “go back in time” to the antics of C and C++: declaration before definition. Try the following:
>
> ```
> Func<int, int> fact = null;
> fact = x => (x == 0) ? 1 : x * fact(x - 1);
> ```
>
> Works like a charm.

Yes, that does work, with one little caveat. C# has mutable references. So make sure you don't accidentally do something like this:

```
Func<int, int> fact = null;
fact = x => (x == 0) ? 1 : x * fact(x - 1);

// Make a new reference to the factorial function
Func<int, int> myFact = fact;

// Use the new reference to calculate the factorial of 4
myFact(4); // returns 24

// Modify the old reference
fact = x => x;

// Again, use the new reference to calculate
myFact(4); // returns 12
```

Of course, this example is a bit contrived, but this could happen when using mutable references. If you use the combinators from [aku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61143/recursive-lambda-expression-to-traverse-a-tree-in-c#61162)'s links, this won't be possible.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming a mythical object TreeItem, that conatins a Children collection to represent your hierarchy.

```
    public void HandleTreeItems(Action<TreeItem> item, TreeItem parent)
    {
        if (parent.Children.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (TreeItem ti in parent.Children)
            {
                HandleTreeItems(item, ti);
            }
        }

        item(parent);
    }
```

Now to call it, passing in the lambda that handles one item, by printing its name to the console.

```
HandleTreeItems(item => { Console.WriteLine(item.Name); }, TreeItemRoot);
```

Comment: HandleTreeItems is not a lambda, it just takes a lambda as argument. Thus this does not answer the specific question.